# Getting user email from form - nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, nodemailer

So I am currently trying to create a newsletter mailer, sent out upon form submit. I have gotten the nodemailer code to work, I just don't know how to get the users email from the client side, into the mailOptions object. (This is a react ecommerce website)

My index.js on the server side is as follows:

```
        const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    secureConnection: true, 
    auth:{
        user: process.env.DB_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.DB_PASS
    },
    tls:{
        rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
})

//new

app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {  

    let mailOptions = {
        from:  process.env.DB_EMAIL,
        to: req.body.userEmail,
        subject:"Welcome to SkyeSkates",
        text: "Whoop Whoop! You are officially part of the team!"
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, success)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("email sent!");
        }
    
    
    })
})
```

And this is my form on the home page of my client side:

```
   <form  action="/submit" class="contact-form">
              <h1>Pssst, hey, you <br/> (yeah, you)</h1>
              <p>Want in on new arrivals, exclusive collabs, sales and more? <br/> Well, you know what to do.</p>
              <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" placeholder='Your email, please'></input>
              <input type="submit" id="send-btn" value="Send Message"></input>
              <br/>
              <small>To see how we may use your information, take a look at our privacy policiy.</small>        
          </form>
```

Comment: I have added my answer kindly confirm that it works ...

Answer (score 0):

make an express.js or node.js server

```
const express = require('express.js')
const app = express()

    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    secureConnection: true, 
    auth:{
        user: process.env.DB_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.DB_PASS
    },
    tls:{
        rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
})




app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {  

    let mailOptions = {
        from:  process.env.DB_EMAIL,
        to: req.body.userEmail,
        subject:"Welcome to SkyeSkates",
        text: "Whoop Whoop! You are officially part of the team!"
    }
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, success)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("email sent!");
        }
    
    
    })
app.redirect('/');

}) 


app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
  console.log("running');
}
```

html form :

```
<div className='fourth-header'>
                    <form  action="/submit" class="contact-form">
                          <h1>Pssst, hey, you <br/> (yeah, you)</h1>
                          <p>Want in on new arrivals, exclusive collabs, sales and more? <br/> Well, you know what to do.</p>
                          <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" placeholder='Your email, please'></input>
                          <input type="submit" id="send-btn" value="Send Message"></input>
                          <br/>
                          <small>To see how we may use your information, take a look at our privacy policiy.</small>        
                      </form> 
                  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But if I do this, I'm just confused as to how I send the userEmail from front end? At the moment it is not working as is.

Comment: well when you submit the html form all input fields are send to the URL specified in `action` attribute of that html form. These form input values will be available on `req` object with property name being same as specified in `name` attribute of input tag

Comment: need any further clarification ?

Comment: Oh okay, that clarification helps a lot thank you! So it kept redirecting me to the login page (which is the '/' path) so I changed it to the home page where this form is located but it still refreshes the page without the sendMail of the nodemailer taking place.

Comment: so if it is still not working it must be issue with how you set paths ...  rule of thumb is to set action of form different from what its own path is . For example if your form lives at `www.someweb.com/survey` you should specify action of form as `/submit_survey` or any thing else different from base url

Comment: I have made an edit; is your issue still unresolved ?

Comment: But When I did that, I was directed to that in my URL. for example I have changed the action to '/getemail' and now I am directed to a new page with the URL ('http://localhost:3000/getemail?userEmail=alexapettitt14%40gmail.com'). So sorry for all the questions but thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: it will be helpful if you edit your question to include the latest code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247754/discussion-between-ht006-and-alexa-pettitt).

Comment: is it working now ?